# Create a checkbox for each object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a small website which allows users to create questions and exams (and also take those exams). Facing a problem with the Create-examview. The user has to be allowed to check any Questions that should be added to the Exam.

Using the following action to create the view, which passes the Questions in a ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    QuestionaireDbContext db = new QuestionaireDbContext();
    ViewBag.Questions = db.Questions;
    return View();
}
```

In my view then, I can call ViewBag.Questions and (should be able to?) use those to create checkboxes for each Question.

I have tried using the extesionmethod for HtmlHelper, [CheckBoxList](http://mvccbl.com/), which I got through NuGet. But the Html.CheckBoxList doesn't seem to be picked up. I tried adding the using as suggested in their documents but that didn't work either.

How can I create a checkbox for each Question and allow the user to select a variaty of them?

My Exam and Question-models for reference:

```
public class Exam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public enum Answers
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AnswerA { get; set; }
    public string AnswerB { get; set; }
    public string AnswerC { get; set; }
    public string AnswerD { get; set; }
    public Answers Correct { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you please update the question with your view code.

Comment: @Amila how can my viewcode be of use when have nothing related to this issue? The use of the CheckBoxList did not work so I am searching for a different solution..

Comment: I don't want to see your entire view. Just wanted to see how you've used CheckBoxList.

Comment: I haven't, because CheckBoxList did not get recognised by the editor. Despite adding references and using-statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create view models to represent what you want to bind to. One possible solution might be

```
public class ExamVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<QuestionVM> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

In you Create method, initialize and populate the ExamVM details including the collection of possible questions, then in the view

```
@model YourAssembly.ExamVM

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Questions[i].ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Questions[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Questions[i].Name)
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ExamVM model)
{
  foreach(QuestionVM q in model.Questions)
  {
    if (q.IsSelected)
    {
      // Save the value of exam.ID and question ID to the database
```

Comment: Why can't I achieve this functionality with my current models? Is there a particular reason I have to create an Exam and Question ViewModel?

Comment: First I know nothing about the `CheckBoxListFor` you referred to and I don't know if it supports your model structure - you haven't even included how your using it. Second, the advantage of view models is you are binding to view to the properties you need for postback. Third, if you were to bind to `ICollection<Question>` you would need to create inputs for all the properties of Question which seems unnecessary and would degrade performance. Fourth, you have no property in your model which indicates which quustions have been selected by the user so how would you know on postback?

Comment: Would you recommend restructuring my current models or use the viewmodels instead?

Comment: No, I would keep you existing models and use separate view models.You can use [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to make mapping data between your model and view model easy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called `EditorTemplates` in your Views/Shared folder.

create a new empty view called _QuestionEditor and add the following code.

```
@model Question

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
//use DisplayFor or LabelFor accordingly
@Html.CheckboxFor(model => true, Model.AnswerA)
@Html.CheckboxFor(model => true, Model.AnswerB)
@Html.CheckboxFor(model => true, Model.AnswerC)
@Html.CheckboxFor(model => true, Model.AnswerD)
```

now in your main view use it as follows

```
@foreach(var question in ViewBag.Questions){
    @Html.EditorFor(item => question)
    //you can specify the template name i.e `"_QuestionEditor"` as the second parameter 
    //if you have more than one editor template for the same type
}
```

This doesn't take into account how you submit your data as you haven't provided any code for that or the model that you use to get the data back into your `post` action